# navbar in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a webpage which is made in Bootstrap 4. On mobile view, the navbar toggler is not going inside navbar as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

Here is the [url](http://ferhan.ferohost.com/) for the webpage. I am wondering what changes do I need to make in the style sheets in order for the navbar and navbar toggler to look good on mobile view. At this moment, the navbar toggler is coming out of the navbar as shown above in the screenshot.

Comment: Please post the code instead of links to external sites

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `navbar-brand` which adjusts the navbar's height in mobile view.
You can alternatively write the fixed min-height of the navbar in css.

```
.navbar
{
   min-height: 55px;
}
```